# Twilio - How to forward all incoming SMS for a number Ruby

Tags: ruby, twilio

How can I forward all incoming text messages to another phone number with Twilio. I'm using Ruby on Rails. All the examples in Twilio docs show PHP examples. Would it be easiest to use their URL, TwiML App or a Messaging service to set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have a Rails app already, then forwarding SMS messages shouldn't be too hard. You will need to set up a route to an action that responds to POST requests. That route will need to return some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to tell Twilio to send the message on to your number.

First you'll want to add the `twilio-ruby` gem to your `Gemfile`

```
gem "twilio-ruby"
```

Then install the gems:

```
$ bundle install
```

Then your controller will look a bit like this:

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:messages]

  def messages
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Message params["Body"], to: YOUR_NUMBER
    end
    render :xml => response.to_xml
  end
end
```

This returns TwiML with a [`<Message>` instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message). By default `<Message>` returns a message to the sender, but if you set the [`to` attribute to the number you want it to forward to, then it will forward the message on](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message#attributes-to).

Finally, you'll need to set your Twilio numbers Message Request URL to a URL that points to that action.

If you want a bit more detail on using Twilio with Rails, check out this blog post on [using Twilio with Rails 4](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: is there a way @philnash to use the original phone number when forwarding the message and not the virtual Twilio number? It makes it impossible to tell whom the message is from.

Comment: @LeoNet I'm afraid not. You could include the number in the body of the text you send. Alternatively, you could use the API to put together an app that you could receive and send messages from, never having to forward but always seeing the sender's number.

Comment: I was afraid so, thank you will build an app to do so as you recommend.